# Is there any CSV Datasource plugin for CakePHP2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, datasource, cakephp-2.3

Cake 1.3 [has a CSV source](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/models/datasources/csv_source.php), but I didn't find any source by using csv.

Does anyone who know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch to the `2.0` branch of the repository: https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/CsvSource.php